# googletest type parameterized tests with incomplete templates

Tags: c++, googletest

Suppose I have a test that compares two instantiations of a template class:

```
TEST_F(fooSuite, fooTest) {
    U<A> tA;
    U<B> tB;
    someCheck(tA, tB);
}
```

I now want to turn this in a [Type-Parameterized Test](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/advanced.md#type-parameterized-tests) for both `U` and `V` because they implement the same interface:

```
template <class T>
class U { ... }

template <class T>
class V { ... }
```

Intuitively, I would want to write something like:

```
template <class TestType>
class fooSuite { };

TYPED_TEST_P(fooSuite, fooTest) {
    TypeParam<A> tA;
    TypeParam<B> tB;
    someCheck(tA, tB);
}

REGISTER_TYPED_TEST_SUITE_P(fooSuite, fooTest);

using TypesToTest = ::testing::Types<U, V>
INSTANTIATE_TYPED_TEST_SUITE_P(fooPrefix, fooSuite, TypesToTest);
```

Naturally, this fails to compile because `U` and `V` require a template argument in this `using` expression.

Is this possible without a major workaround creating wrapper classes to pass around?

Comment: Your U and V are not incomplete types, they are templates. I have never used typed tests, but after a quick look into the docs, you're supposed to inject types into the tests and not templates.

Comment: True, "incomplete type" was the wrong description. However, the problem that I can not simply use `U` and `V` in the using statement without their template arguments remains the same. I reformulated this part of the question.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `std::tuple` as your test fixture's template parameter, which would allow passing the complete types.

```
template <typename Tuple>
class FooSuite : public ::testing::Test
{
public:
    template<typename TA, typename TB>
    void SomeCheck(TA tA, TB tB)
    {
        // Check expectations here
    }
};

TYPED_TEST_SUITE_P(FooSuite);

TYPED_TEST_P(FooSuite, FooTest) {
    using TA = typename std::tuple_element<0, TypeParam>::type;
    using TB = typename std::tuple_element<1, TypeParam>::type;
    TA tA;
    TB tB;
    this->SomeCheck(tA, tB);
}

REGISTER_TYPED_TEST_SUITE_P(FooSuite, FooTest);

using TypesToTest = Types<
    std::tuple<U<A>, U<B>>,
    std::tuple<V<A>, V<B>>
>;

INSTANTIATE_TYPED_TEST_SUITE_P(FooPrefix, FooSuite, TypesToTest);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is this possible without a major workaround creating wrapper classes to pass around?

AFAICS from the docs, the answer is: no, you cant. The problem is that `TestingTypes` takes types but you want to pass templates. The only solution I can see is to create a simple wrapper type to carry the template of interest into the test function and instantiate it there with the desired template parameter.

Disclaimer: I am not familiar enough with google test, maybe there is a way how to do it.

However depending on what exactly you mean with "major workaround", the following code illustrates a possible approach, which I think should work.  The effort is not too bad, I think.

```
template <class T>
class U { };

template <class T>
class V {  };

class A{};
class B{};

template<template<class> typename UorV>
struct TemplateHolder {
    template<class Arg>
    using type = UorV<Arg>;
};

template<class T, class Arg>
using instantiate_t = typename T::template type<Arg>;

// Mimick what I suspect the google testing::Types and TypeParam are. 
template<class... Ts>
struct TestingTypes {};

using types_to_test = TestingTypes<TemplateHolder<U>, TemplateHolder<V>>;



int main( void ) {

    using TypeParam = TemplateHolder<U>;
    using ActualTypeToTestA = instantiate_t<TestingType, A>;
    using ActualTypeToTestB = instantiate_t<TestingType, B>;

    static_assert(std::is_same_v<ActualTypeToTestA, U<A>>);
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<ActualTypeToTestB, U<B>>);
    return 0;
}
```

[Live code here](https://godbolt.org/z/dU66TC)